# Is there a way to see the timestamp of the changes in a file when running a diff during a merge conflict?

Tags: git, command-line, command-line-arguments

On occasion, I find myself in a situation where I need to know when (as in date and time) a specific change was made on a conflicted file while resolving a merge conflict, so that I can decide if I want to take one over the other or edit the file.

In those situations, I use `git blame` on the relevant file within their respective branches and get the date and times for the specific changes I'm interested in. This works fine, however I feel there should be an easier way to do this.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a better way to achieve this? I've checked `git` documentation but haven't been able to find anything that would make this process easier. Doesn't have to be in `git` I'd be happy to find out alternative approaches/tools..etc

Comment: afaik the Git plugins for all the programming editors will do this for you, in vim I type ":Git blame" straight from the mergetool buffer and that's all it takes.

Comment: `git blame` is fine for the resulting file. I'd like to see the timestamps of all the other changes for that file including old and new. Essentially something like a combination of `git diff` and `git blame` where each diff would also have a corresponding timestamp

Answer (score 0):

No.  There isn't one, because commits don't hold *changes*, they hold *snapshots*.  The merge operation looks only at three snapshots: the merge base commit, and the two branch tip commits.

> I can work around it by running `git blame` on those files in their respective branches ...

This is, at least in Git, a fundamentally different operation.  The `git blame` (or `git annotate`) command walks through the graph one commit at a time, backwards (as usual), comparing some files-and-lines within each parent-and-child commit-pair.  This locates a specific *earlier* commit in the chain, in which a specific line that appears in the *last* commit in the chain, still appears in that earlier commit.  Blame in effect does this once for each source line in the *starting* commit—well, the *latest* commit; maybe you would call that the *end* rather than the *start* one—but optimized to make it go fast.

Let's draw this as a concrete (but simple) example—`git blame` handles more complex cases that include branch-and-merge subgraphs, but we'll ignore these while constructing the example.  Suppose we have the following:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

i.e., your current commit is commit `J`, and you run `git merge branch2`.  Git will locate the *merge base* commit, `H`, on its own, and, in effect, run two `git diff`s:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git will now attempt to combine the two sets of changes.  If file *F* appears in all three commits, `H` and `J` and `L`, but is *different* in all three commits, the two separate diff outputs will have some changes for *F* in both diffs.  These changes need to be *combined* into a single change that can be applied to the copy of *F* that appears in commit `H`.

When these changes overlap (touch the same lines of *F* in `H`) or abut (the end of either-side's change is just at the edge of the start of a different change on the other side, again referring to the copy of *F* in `H`), this is a *merge conflict*.

What I think you want is a tool that will, given that we know `H`-vs-`J` and `H`-vs-`L` both "touch" some line(s) in *F*, run `git blame -L<range> H^@..J` and `git blame -L<range> H^@..L` for the appropriate line-ranges (based on the copy of *F* in `H` as modified in `J` and `L` respectively).  The two `<range>` expressions may differ if `J` and `L` have, overall, added or deleted lines above the point in which these lines appear in `H`.

These two `git blame` will inspect commits `J`, then `I`, then `H` (for the first case) and `L`, then `K`, then `H` (for the second).  These inspections are pretty much symmetric, so in thinking about the problem, we can just look at one "side".  We'll repeat the operation—but maybe with different line numbers, as noted above—for the other.  Because there *was* a merge conflict, we know that the lines in question *did* change in `H`-vs-`J`.  Therefore, they:

- changed in `H`-vs-`I` and not in `I`-vs-`J`, or
- did not change in `H`-vs-`I` but did change in `I`-vs-`J`, or
- changed in *both* `H`-vs-`I` *and* `I`-vs-`J`

so `git blame` will, for each line in the range, assign it to commit `I` or commit `J`.

The *time stamps* of commits `I` and `J` are not the real item of interest here.  Rather, the *commit hashes* are interesting: they identify which commit(s) contributed to the change.

The biggest complication is that it's possible that, for each line in the range, the contribution comes from a *different commit*.  Since `git merge` looks only at `H`-vs-`J`, perhaps a two-line change:

```
-first
-second
+1st
+2nd
```

is really a one-line change that replaces "first" with "1st" in `I`, and then a one-line change that replaces "second" with "2nd" in `J`.

When the commit ranges in the merge are larger, as in:

```
          A--B--C--D--...--Y--Z   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--...--o   <-- branch2
```

the diff from merge base commit `*` to commit `Z` might have a 30-line "change" with contributions from, say, 15 of the 26 commits represented by the `A-B-...-Z` sequence.  So you will, potentially at least, need a lot of information.

It might be nice if you could get `git merge` to run the appropriate `git blame` for you, but you can't.  What you *can* do is write your own tool to automate this:

- Given that you know a suitable specifier for the current (`HEAD`) commit (it's `HEAD`), and you have a specifier for the *other* commit—`L` in our simple example above—available, during a conflicted merge, under the name `MERGE_HEAD`, you must find the *merge base* commit hash.  The command that does this is `git merge-base`.

  There is a complication: there may be more than one merge base.  Use `git merge-base --all` to find *all* the merge bases (as `git merge` will do by default).  If there is more than one, decide how to handle this.  Merge's default is to merge the merge bases, committing the result as a temporary commit whose hash ID is inaccessible to you.  (It might be nice if `git merge` saved this hash ID somewhere, for the duration of the conflicted merge, but it doesn't.  The temporary commit may not even be hooked up to the commit graph in the first place; I haven't checked.  Either way, it's not available, so there's no real point in pursuing this path unless you modify Git to make it available.)  I don't know offhand a good way to handle this, other than perhaps to choose all the merge bases as stop-points for `git blame`.
- Anyway, having found the merge base or bases (and figured out what to do in the case of more than one), you can now have your tool run `git blame`.  The hard part here is coming up with the right line numbers.
- The magic-looking `H^@` syntax in `H^@..HEAD` or `H^@..MERGE_HEAD` just tells `git blame` that it can stop looking when it reaches any of `H`'s parent commits, which potentially speeds up its operation.  Given appropriate `-L` restrictions, this may be unnecessary.  It's probably still a good idea—and in fact, you might want to use `--ancestry-path` here as well, if `git blame` obeys `--ancestry-path`.  (I have not tested this.)  That will prevent `git blame` from going down any blind alleys that might turn up in a more complex graph.

The tool can probably just leave you with `git blame`'s output unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the commits made on a specific file we can use

`git log filename`

we can get all differences on a file between two commits

`git diff commit1 commit2 -- filename`